# How to set default value if Select criteria does not match using SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, stored-procedures, case

The following procedure only returns values where my WHERE conditions are met but ignores the default values (1 and R.amount) I am trying to set here.

How can I write this correctly so that exchangeRate is set to 1 and amountUSD is set to R.amount if R.currency equals USD ?

```
SELECT      R.amount,
            R.currency,
            (
                    SELECT      (CASE WHEN R.currency = 'USD' THEN 1 ELSE E.exchange_rate END) AS exchangeRate,
                                (CASE WHEN R.currency = 'USD' THEN R.amount ELSE (R.amount * E.exchange_rate) END) AS amountUSD
                    FROM        Exchange_Rates E
                    WHERE       E.from_currency = R.currency
                    AND         E.to_currency = 'USD'
                    FOR XML     PATH(''), ELEMENTS, TYPE
            )
FROM        LogRequests R
FOR XML PATH('requests'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT('ranks')
```

Comment: Can you show some sample data and desired output?  What are you concatenating together?

Comment: I just want to check whether R.currency is USD. If yes then I want to set exchangeRate to 1 and amountUSD to R.amount. If not then I want to run the sub query to fetch the exchange rate and calculate the amountUSD based on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect what you need is to put the rows in the `Exchange_Rates` table.  Something like this:

```
SELECT      R.amount,
            R.currency,
            (
                    SELECT      E.exchange_rate AS exchangeRate,
                                (R.amount * E.exchange_rate)AS amountUSD
                    FROM        ((SELECT e.from_currency, e.to_currency, e.exchange_rate
                                  FROM Exchange_Rates E
                                 ) UNION ALL
                                 (SELECT 'USD', 'USD', 1)
                                ) E
                    WHERE       E.from_currency = R.currency
                    AND         E.to_currency = 'USD'
                    FOR XML     PATH(''), ELEMENTS, TYPE
            )
FROM        LogRequests R
FOR XML PATH('requests'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT('ranks');
```

However, I would recommend that you insert the currency pairs before the query.  Something like this:

```
insert into Exchange_Rates(from_currency, to_currency, exchange_rate)
    select distinct to_currency, to_currrency, 1
    from exchange_rates;
```